# Check functions on onsubmit doenst work jquery contactform

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, validation

Update..

code works now

had to change the validation statement on form submit. Removed the valid vars etc etc. but it works now Thanks

fixed onsubmit to

```
$('form').on("submit", function(e) {

            //Prevent default
            e.preventDefault();

                    if(validateName() & validateSubject() & validateEmail() & validateMessage())
                    {
                        $('form #status').removeClass().addClass('processing').html('Processing...').fadeIn('fast');

                        // maak variable met alle data die verstuurd kan worden
                        var formData = $('form').serialize();

                        //functie om data naar server te sturen
                        submitForm(formData);
                        return true;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        $('form #status').removeClass().addClass('error')
                            .html('<strong>Form is not filled in correctly</strong>').fadeIn('fast')
                        return false;
                    }

            });
```

Comment: This part doesn't make sense: "now I wanted to enter some sever side validation using jquery" jQuery is client side...

Comment: I don't see anything major wrong with your code

Comment: Although you may want to set `valid` back to `''` if all the fields are valid. Slight logic problem there.

Comment: jquery is client side... When i submit with all fields filled in it gives a error that message field returned a error so valid is filled.. and when all fields are emty it still sends the form data but then the php returns a error because i do some validation checking on empty...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you aren't preventing the submission of your form. Instead, you're hooking into the Submit button and then just showing an error message if there's a problem (but the form gets submitted anyway so the error message isn't helpful).

There are a couple things you could/should do to solve this. First of all, you probably want to attach your validation code to the form's submit event (rather than the submit button's click event). This will ensure that if you offer other ways to submit the form in the future you won't need to maintain the validation hooks on each method individually. So instead of:

```
$('form #submit').click(function(e) {
```

You probably want:

```
$('form').on("submit", function(e) {
```

Secondarily, if there's a problem with the form, you want to return `false` in the submit handler. This will cause an implicit `e.preventDefault()`, which will stop the form from submitting:

```
if (valid != '') {
    $('form #status').removeClass().addClass('error')
        .html('<strong>Correct these errors<BR></strong>' + valid).fadeIn('fast');
    return false; //stop form submission
    //Or you could do e.preventDefault(); if you're not ready to end the function yet.
}
```

That should resolve your most immediate issue. Keep at it!

Comment: He is stopping the click event from submitting the form already. That of course doesn't prevent pressing enter from submitting the form though.

Comment: How do i prevent enters? $('form #submit').bind("keypress", function(e) { and encapsulate the rest of the code in it?

Comment: @r2get Check the first part of my answer. You want to be listening for the form submit event, not the clicking of the submit button.

Comment: it workst... you're great... going further now to a registration form haha